# grails / gorm / org.hibernate.type at TRACE prints nothing

Tags: hibernate, logging, grails, groovy

I can't configure **org.hibernate.type** (logging bind variables used in hibernate prepared statements) using log4j.xml, but can using the log4j DSL in Config.groovy.

We need to configure logging for different environments without building different WARs for each and thus need to use log4j.xml rather than the DSL, if possible.

Have put

`<logger name="org.hibernate.type">
    <level value="TRACE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</logger>`

but the bindings don't print. Previously in the DSL they did. 

`log4j = {
...`

trace 'org.hibernate.type'
}

very strange, esp as other hibernate logging is controllable via log4j.xml.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

As an aside, is using the DSL within Config.groovy recommended as best practice for managing configuration accross environments flexibly - a compiled object containing configuration seems surprising - but am new to grails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use separate config files for each server. To have a custom config file in your server's home folder, put something like the following into config.groovy:

```
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${userHome}/customConfig.groovy" ]
```

Then, create `customConfig.groovy` in your web server's home folder (something like `vim ~tomcat/customConfig.groovy` if you're using Linux & Tomcat) and override any properties you want. The only snag is that for the logging DSL, you need to provide the whole logging block in here (you can't just override selected properties like you can with most other config settings).

This way, you only have to restart your web application when configuration changes and you don't have to have separate builds for different servers.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your logging based on the environment in the Config.groovy file

```
// set per-environment 
environments {
    development {
       log4j = {
          ...
       }
    }
    test {
       log4j = {
          ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this - that may be what we end up doing - however doesn't allow changes in logging levels without a re-compile which is quite a restriction. It can be useful to temporarily restart servers, up log levels for messages traces, queue trace, SQL etc, then bring the level back down and restoring.